# Undefined function getTeam()

Tags: php

So what I want to do is to show who's in a team. I've created a function called getTeam().

```
class admin
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($conn)
    {
        return $this->db;
    }
    public function getTeam($teamname)
    {
       try
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_players` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `tbl_teams` WHERE team_name=:team_name)";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindparam(":team_name", $teamname);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my dbconnect I'm using

```
session_start();
$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "";
$DB_name = "project_fifa";

try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
include ('assets/classes/admin.php');
$user = new admin($conn);
```

So now I'm trying to use the function here

```
require('../dbconnect.php');

if(isset($_POST['findteam'])){
$teamname = $_POST['teamname'];
getTeam($teamname);
}
```

It can't find the function and I don't know why.

Comment: getTeam() is a function of the class. You need to apply it to a class instance, like $user->getTeam($teamname)

Comment: You are trying to access a function that's inside the class `admin` use `$user->getTeam($teamname);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing code with OOPS, First you have to learn some basics about it [Read it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

**Object(new) :**
To create an instance of a class, the new keyword must be used. An object will always be created unless the object has a constructor defined that throws an exception on error. Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement).

If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created. If the class is in a namespace, its fully qualified name must be used when doing this.

```
 $adminObject = new admin(); 
 $adminObject->getTeam($teamname);
```

Comment: maybe testObject would like to be called adminObject

Comment: Thanks alot. I should've known. Totally looked over it.